# got npm module : How to retry for POST requests?

Tags: node.js, npm, node.js-got

The below example is for GET requests, but does not work for POST requests. How can I make it work for POST?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#retry

```
const got = require('got')
const retry = {
  retry: {
    retries: 3
  }
}
got('http://localhost:3000/retry', retry).then(({ body }) => {
  console.log(body);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#gotposturl-options`

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have a salesforce composite [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm] which return 500 for sub-requests, I want a retry mechanism if 1st sub-request retruns a 500.

Comment: It worked for the GET request not because the retries were set to 3, but because the default limit is set to 2 in the got package. The default retry limit to 2 is set for methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'HEAD', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE']

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sample POST request with retry count as 3. If you want to disable retry set retry count to 0.

```
const got = require('got');
start()
async function start() {
 var response = await request()
 console.log(response);  
}

async function request() {
try {
    const response = await got.post('https://example.com', { retry: { limit: 3, methods: ["GET", "POST"] } });
    return response.body
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.body);   
    return error
 }
}
```

For POST Add Methods as shown below, by default got does not support retries for POST

> **`got.post('https://example.com', { retry: { limit: 1, methods: ["GET", "POST"] } });`**